# Are there any multi-physics with magnets and gravity software simulators?

Tags: resource-recommendations, simulations, software

I'm looking for something like SolidWorks / Autodesk Inventor but with electromagnetism built-in.

Do you know of such software?

Comment: This might be of interest:  https://www.comsol.com/comsol-multiphysics  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I found it also but seems extremely complicated

Comment: @user3157407 it is, but it needs to be to include everything you want.